# Rotating effect not working after animation

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I want to rotate the inner circle when hover over outer circle, its works fine if I don't apply animation to it. But if I apply animation, inner circle does not rotate on hover. My animation makes inner circle rotate once only.

```css
body, html {
  height: 100%;
}

.main-content {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
}

.box-container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
.box-container ul {
  list-style: none;
}
.box-container .box {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: pink;
  border-radius: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.box-container .box span {
  transform-origin: 0% 0%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-top: -20px;
  margin-left: -20px;
  display: block;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background: #58C9B9;
  color: #fff;
  line-height: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  transform-origin: calc(100% - 20px) calc(100% - 20px);
}
.box-container .box:hover span {
  background: #4F86C6;
  transform: rotateY(360deg);
  transition: .5s;
}

.animate1 {
  animation: animate .5s ease-in-out  forwards;
}

.animate2 {
  animation: animate .5s ease-in-out .5s  forwards;
}

.animate3 {
  animation: animate .5s ease-in-out 1.0s  forwards;
}

@keyframes animate {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: rotateY(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: rotateY(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="main-content">
    <div class="box-container">
      <ul class="list-unstyle list-inline">
          <li class="box "><span class="animate1">20%</span></li>
          <li class="box "><span class="animate2">40%</span></li>
          <li class="box "><span class="animate3">50%</span></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<div>
```

Comment: How to solve it??

Comment: I'm added the answer below.

Answer (score 3):

Remove property `forwards` from `animation-fill-mode` and then it works fine, as below.

> animation-fill-mode:forwards - After the animation ends, 
>   the animation will apply the property values for the time the animation ended.

Over-here animation ends at `360deg` when using `forwards`.

**Update -**

And in your case you need to use `forwards` just to `fade-in span tag` i.e. from `opacity 0 to 1`, so for that you can declare `two different animation`.

```css
body, html {
  height: 100%;
}

.main-content {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
}

.box-container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
.box-container ul {
  list-style: none;
}
.box-container .box {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: pink;
  border-radius: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.box-container .box span {
  transform-origin: 0% 0%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-top: -20px;
  margin-left: -20px;
  display: block;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background: #58C9B9;
  color: #fff;
  line-height: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  transform-origin: calc(100% - 20px) calc(100% - 20px);
  opacity:0;
  transform:rotate(0deg);
}
li:nth-child(1):hover > .animate1{
  transition:.5s ease;
  transform:rotateY(360deg);
}
li:nth-child(2):hover > .animate2{
  transition:.5s ease;
   transform:rotateY(360deg);
}
li:nth-child(3):hover > .animate3{
  transition:.5s ease;
  transform:rotateY(360deg);
}

.animate1{
  animation: animate .5s ease-in-out,  opty .5s ease-in-out forwards;
}
.animate2 {
  animation: animate .5s ease-in-out .5s,  opty .5s ease-in-out forwards .5s;
}

.animate3 {
  animation: animate .5s ease-in-out 1.0s, opty .5s ease-in-out forwards 1s;
}

@keyframes animate {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: rotateY(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: rotateY(360deg);
  }
}
@keyframes opty {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="main-content">
    <div class="box-container">
      <ul class="list-unstyle list-inline">
          <li class="box "><span class="animate1">20%</span></li>
          <li class="box "><span class="animate2">40%</span></li>
          <li class="box "><span class="animate3">50%</span></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<div>
```

Comment: I need forwards because I want to hide inner box before I do animation to all boxes . There will be .box-container .box span{opacity:0}

Comment: @KrishnaRana you can assign separate animation for opacity as above. Just don't add that on transform.

Comment: Welcome @KrishnaRana :-)

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is with your **animation** property .I'm edited it and it's working fine.I'm added the snippet below.

```css
body, html {
  height: 100%;
}

.main-content {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
}

.box-container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
.box-container ul {
  list-style: none;
}
.box-container .box {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: pink;
  border-radius: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.box-container .box span {
  transform-origin: 0% 0%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-top: -20px;
  margin-left: -20px;
  display: block;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background: #58C9B9;
  color: #fff;
  line-height: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  transform-origin: calc(100% - 20px) calc(100% - 20px);
}
.box-container .box:hover span {
  background: #4F86C6;
  transform: rotateY(360deg);
  transition: .5s;
}

.animate1 {
  animation: animate .5s ease-in-out 1;
}

.animate2 {
  animation: animate .5s ease-in-out .5s;
}

.animate3 {
  animation: animate .5s ease-in-out 1s;
}

@keyframes animate {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: rotateY(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: rotateY(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="main-content">
    <div class="box-container">
      <ul class="list-unstyle list-inline">
          <li class="box "><span class="animate1">20%</span></li>
          <li class="box "><span class="animate2">40%</span></li>
          <li class="box "><span class="animate3">50%</span></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<div>
```

Comment: I need forwards because I want to hide inner box before I do animation to all boxes . There will be .box-container .box span{opacity:0}